# In Oracle, repeatedly assign values from a set to column

Tags: oracle

I have a table in Oracle that has a column that I would like to assign a value to from a set of possible values. I like to assign the values in order of the set, repeatedly, for the entire table.

**For example:**

If the set of values is {1, 2, 3}. I'd like to assign the values in this pattern until the last row is reached:

```
rowNum    someCol      valueCol
  1        this            1
  2         is             2
  3        some            3
  4        other           1
  5        column          2
  6         in             3
  7         the            1
  8        table           2
```

I can't figure out how to do this with a traditional update statement. Anone that could help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Modulo to achieve desire result

```
UPDATE TableName
SET valueCol= CASE  WHEN rowNum % 3 == 1 then 1
                    WHEN rowNum % 3 == 2 then 2
                    WHEN rowNum % 3 == 0 then 3
              END
```

Comment: It's some strange mix Oracle and Java syntaxes =)

Comment: Had to change syntax to meet Oracle standards, but this is the correct logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
update tablename 
  set valuecol = case mod(rownum, 3) when 0 then 3 else mod(rownum, 3) end
;
```